# One query string for both ascending and descending sort operations

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm using the following logic to sort the data read from an SQL database-

```
<a href='string_functions.php?sort=desc'>Sort By Type</a>
<?php  
    if( isset( $_GET['sort'] ) and $_GET['sort'] == 'desc')  {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM `function list` ORDER BY `function type` DESC";
    } else {
        #Read from Database
        $query = "SELECT * FROM `function list`";
    }
    $data_buffer = $conn -> query($query);
?>
```

I'm then using **`$data_buffer`** to display the tuples from the table **`function list`**

I want to make -

```
<a href='string_functions.php?sort=desc'>Sort By Type</a>
```

to toggle for both **ASC** and **DESC** operations. Is it possible to do so?

I'm aware that I can use two links like -

```
<a href='string_functions.php?sort=asc'>Sort By Type</a>
<a href='string_functions.php?sort=desc'>Sort By Type</a>
```

each for different operations, but is it possible to do so by using just one link?

Comment: You can use Javascript with a onlick event to change the inner href link,not that well versed in JS to give an answer,just a hint.

Comment: I'm aware that it can be done on the client side, but I want to do this on the server side

Comment: You're going to need some sort of client side logic to do this to avoid page refreshing (you could update the Dom in an Ajax callback). The reason you can't handle the toggle on the server is because the page is processed on the server and then rendered to the client, this only happens on the initial page request, so subsequent requests will refresh the page to set the new label.   If you use Ajax you could dynamically refresh the label as you click it

Comment: @Alex, I did it! I modified a little and added CSS it works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of CSS and little mod of the code I was able to do it

**PHP:**

```
<?php  
    if(isset( $_GET['sort'] ) and $_GET['sort'] == 'desc')
        $hide = 'hide';
    else
        $hide = '';
?>
<a href='string_functions.php?sort=desc' class="<?php echo $hide;?>">Sort By Type(DESC)</a>
<?php  
    if( isset( $_GET['sort'] ) and $_GET['sort'] == 'desc' )  {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM `function list` ORDER BY `function type` DESC";
        ?>
        <a href='string_functions.php?sort=asc'>Sort By Type(ASC)</a>
    <?php 
    } else if(isset( $_GET['sort'] ) and $_GET['sort'] == 'asc' ) { ?>
    <?php
        #Read from Database
        $query = "SELECT * FROM `function list` ORDER BY `function type` ASC";
    } else {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM `function list`";
    }
    $data_buffer = $conn -> query($query);
?>
```

**CSS:**

```
<style>
    .hide {
        display: none;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested this code but it will help you
and i have used **session** because it will help you in pagination,
but its not compulsory you can use simple variable also as per you need

```
<?php
  if( isset( $_GET['sort'] ) and $_GET['sort'] == 'desc')
  {
   $_SESSION['sort_type']='DESC'; //you can set using normal variable also instead of SESSION
   $_SESSION['sort_arrow']='v';
   $_SESSION['sort_link']='asc';
  }
  else
  {
    $_SESSION['sort_type']='ASC';
    $_SESSION['sort_arrow']='^';
    $_SESSION['sort_link']='desc';
  }

  $query = "SELECT * FROM `function list` ORDER BY `function type` '".$_SESSION['sort_type']."'";
  ?>
  <a href="string_functions.php?sort=<?php echo $_SESSION['sort_link'];?>">
   <?php echo $_SESSION['sort_arrow'];?>
</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
<a href='string_functions.php?sort=desc'>Sort By Type</a>
```

replace with:

```
if(isset( $_GET['sort'] ) and $_GET['sort'] == 'desc') 
    echo "<a href='string_functions.php?sort=asc'>ASC</a>";
else
    echo "<a href='string_functions.php?sort=desc'>DESC</a>";
```